# What, after reputation, determines the order of users on the /users page?

Tags: support, reputation, users

Yesterday I got to be exactly at the same reputation points level as another users, on the main [/users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users) -> [all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) page.

My info showed up on the page **before** the user that already had that reputation level. I expected to be listed after that person, as I was later to arrive at that same reputation level.

The ordering might be a random result. Or it is because I have more gold badges, or because my name is sorted before the other person's.

It is not because I have a lower user number, not because I have been at the site longer (probably related to the user number) and not because I have more total badges (I have far less).

What determines the ordering on the /users pages when the reputation is exactly the same? Or more specific, what caused me to be listed first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Experimentally](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?page=77&tab=reputation&filter=all), users with the same reputation seem to be listed in decreasing order of ID number. In other words, whoever joined the site most recently is listed first.

This doesn't carry over in the voters and editors tab. There, reputation is the second criterion but decreasing ID isn't the third criterion.

Comment: I clicked through 15+ users there and that observation seems indeed to be right. If this is not just an artefact of the underlying SQL, but on purpose, then an explanation might be that the person achieving a rep level quicker, is listed first.